# Product of principal and first eigenvalue

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

If $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R^n}, n \ge 3$ and let $\lambda_1$ be the first eigenvalue of $-\Delta $ on $H^1_0(\Omega)$ and $\alpha_1$ the principal eigenvalue of $K$, the Green operator of $-\Delta $ on $H^1_0(\Omega)$. I heard that $\lambda_1 \alpha_1=1$
How do I go about showing this?

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, isn't the Green's operator an inverse so this should be trivial?

Comment: yeah it's supposed to be easy. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I suggest you first write the full description of your problem. What is the Green operator? What are "first eigenvalue" and "principal eigenvalue"? You shouldn't assume others to do this work (in any case, it makes people less likely to answer).

Comment: @CameronWilliams  The Green operator is the weak solution to the poisson equation with h on the right hand side. the first eigenvalue is the smallest λ1 such $−Δu=λ_1u$ Finally the principal eigenvalue is$ max_{||v||=1}<Av,v>$.  Can you elaborate a bit more?